# Disabling logging messages from org.apache.fontbox and ...pdfbox

Tags: java, pdfbox, apache-commons-logging

I use PDFbox to read PDF files; I understand that it does not use Log4j, it uses apache's common logging (I was surprised to hear this, since its Maven configuration includes Log4j v1).

When I run my program, I get messages like:

```
18:13:20.093 [SwingWorker-pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.fontbox.ttf.PostScriptTable - No PostScript name information is provided for the font CourierNewPS-BoldMT
18:13:20.102 [SwingWorker-pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable - Type 4 GSUB lookup table is not supported and will be ignored
18:13:20.102 [SwingWorker-pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable - Type 6 GSUB lookup table is not supported and will be ignored
18:13:20.102 [SwingWorker-pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable - Type 6 GSUB lookup table is not supported and will be ignored
```

(68 messages about GlyphSubstitutionTable), and

```
18:13:20.163 [SwingWorker-pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.fontbox.ttf.GlyphSubstitutionTable - Type 4 GSUB lookup table is not supported and will be ignored
18:13:20.476 [Finalizer] DEBUG org.apache.pdfbox.io.ScratchFileBuffer - ScratchFileBuffer not closed!
18:13:23.327 [Finalizer] DEBUG org.apache.pdfbox.io.ScratchFileBuffer - ScratchFileBuffer not closed!
```

I have tried putting a `commons-logging.properties` file in `src/main/resources` containing

```
org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog
```

I have tried putting the code `java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.pdfbox").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF)` into a static initializer of the class containing the `static void main` method of my program.

I have tried putting

```
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log",  "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");
```

into that static initializer, separately and together with the previous code.

When I read the PDF in my code, I still get the log messages mentioned above with any and all of the above attempted fixes. How can I eliminate them; I would prefer to just limit them to warning, error, and severe messaages instead of eliminating all messages, but at this point I'll take suggestions for either one.

Comment: What I do is to add log4j2 and set the log level in the XML file (commons logging is between your code and the actual logging library). PDFBox doesn't use log4j, maybe an older version.

Comment: @tilman Hausherr -- My apologies, it isn't PDFBox that gets the older version of log4j included via Maven, it's Tesseract. I use both and just got confused which one I meant.

I tried to do as you suggested -- included log4j api and core (I already had core, but not api) and added a configuration line to log4j.properties, but I still get all those messages. I'll see what I can do about learning how to use XML and see it that does better for some reason.

Comment: log4j2 uses an xml config file only AFAIK. Here's mine (log4j2,xml): <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p %C{2}:%L - %m%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="org.springframework" level="warn" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>

Comment: @arcy  I am having the same problem and it seems that no matter what I do, I cannot get it to stop logging. Did you ever find a solution? I am running this in an aws lambda so I do not have a Main.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Main {
static {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(
        "org.apache").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE);
}
// ...
```

has helped me to disable warnings from fontbox also.

While `"org.apache.pdfbox"` only disables pdfbox warnings, not fontbox ones.

And `"org.apache.fontbox"` somehow does not disable fontbox warnings.

Comment: didnt work......